# Rails 4.0 - NameError uninitialized contant - has_many relationship with non-conventional foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following table that I am trying to store messages between users in. I have set up the relationships to the best of my ability, but I am getting a `NameError in Messages#index`*`uninitialized constant Member::messages`*

Database Schema for messages table

```
create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.text     "message",    null: false
  t.boolean  "read",       null: false
  t.integer  "from_id",    null: false
  t.integer  "to_id",      null: false
end
```

Member model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => :messages, :foreign_key => "to_id"
end
```

Messages Model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

ApplicationController with helper method

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :unread_messages

  def unread_messages
    @unread_messages ||= current_user.received_messages.where(:unread => true) unless current_user.received_messages.nil?
  end
end
```

I am receiving the error during this statement in the aplication.html.erb layout template

`<span class="badge"><%= unread_messages.count %></span>`

What could be causing this problem. This is a very generic error, and usually means that I forgot to setup the association, but this association is different and I have not had to do one before that went outside of the default naming conventions... Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:class_name` key should be "Message".